# Write-Eventlog to create events

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-event-log

I try to create events with similar codes like this:

```
Write-EventLog -LogName 'Windows PowerShell' -Source PowerShell -EventId 12345 -EntryType Information -Message 'Script started'
```

Creation process is seemly successful, but I cannot found the event in the Event Viewer.

Comment: Works for me: `Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ LogName = 'Windows PowerShell'; Id = '12345' }`

Comment: @jscott : But it isn't working for all IDs, for example cannot create `6008` with this code.

Comment: [Yes, 6008 works too](http://imgur.com/a/Mk4yL). Please consider editing your question to include the exact details of what you're doing and what is/isn't working.

Comment: @jscott : I got an error message, that this source cannot have specified eventID. But it is okay at this time! Thanks for your help!